# searching regex for zero to n and zero to one

Tags: regex

I want to parse a string for

- zero to many occurrences of one char
- followed by zero or one occurence of another char

Valid examples (x = any other char(s) but A or B, no digit filtering at this point)

```
xAxBx
xAxAxBx
x
xB
xBx
```

Invalid examples

```
xBxAx
xAxBxAx
xAxBxBx
Ax
A
```

"something" followed by "something containing zero or more "A"s" followed by "something containing zero or one "B"".

The background is some auto-detection of number formatting (zero or some group separators followed by zero or one decimal separator, I know I must escape dots or spaces for A or B)

I'm playing around in http://regexr.com/ but I haven't got it so far...

**Update (2)**

Trying to better/shorter describe my pattern:

- something except A or B
- repeat: A followed by something except A or B
- no or one B followed by something except A or nothing

So the string might end with B but not begin with A or B and no A shall be followed by A or B.

**Update (3)**

With the pattern

```
^[^AB]+(A[^AB]*)*(B[^AB]*)?$
```

- the string may end with an A (like in xxxAxxAAAxxxAxxxxA)
- multiple A may stand together (also like in xxxAxxAAAxxxAxxxxA)

The pattern works regarding

- no A or B at the beginning
- only one B after the As

(testing at http://regexr.com/)

Comment: So, what was the closest attempt at regexr.com?

Comment: And do you want a true/false result or extract those chars?  Are you sure you need/want RegEx?

Comment: Just true/false, it's a quick pre-check before diving deeper into the string (supporting an older inhouse api). Current attempt is "([^AB].*[A*])" for "something followed by zero or many As"

Comment: Does `xA` and `xAx` valid?

Comment: @Niitaku yes, it does

Comment: Why is `A` invalid when you mentioned `zero` occurrence in both requirements.

Comment: @anubhava: The string shall not start with A or B (see "something" note in the question) - current attempt is "([^AB].*[A*][^B]*[B?])", but more Bs are valid with this pattern...

Comment: following your rules, xAxBx should be invalid (because is it followed by one more "something" after B) and xAxAxBx should be too because there are 2 consecutive 'xA'. Or maybe you forgot to mention that those pattern can repeat? If so, is it the whole pattern that can repeat, or the subpatterns?

Comment: @Kaddath, sorry, I'm a regex beginner, the hint is "some auto-detection of number formatting", ignoring digit checking at this point, just a quick true/false pre-check for "zero or some group separators followed by zero or one decimal separator"

Comment: one question more before i try to propose something: do you want the regex to validate the whole string, or just search if the pattern is found inside?

Comment: @Kaddath the whole String. (I've updated the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//"^[^AB]+(A[^AB]*)*(B[^AB]*)*$"
//"^[^AB]+(A[^AB]*)*(B[^AB]*)?$"
  "^[^AB]+(A[^AB]+)*(B[^AB]*)?$"
```

Comment: Thank you. But according to http://regexr.com/ multiple B are possible. I'll try to better describe my pattern in the question.

Comment: Corrected, with a `?` instead of a `*` for the last group.

Comment: Thank you. I still have to reflect my question update with the pattern, but it's a good template. In case no "perfect pattern" comes in another answer, I'll upvote you today (1:15pm here) :-)

Comment: If you have a counter example where this doesn't work then add it to the question.

Comment: btw: sorry for my nonsense comment, "upvoted" and "answered" are different thing, so I've upvoted your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: your last update looks like the perfect pattern to a regex beginner, still testing...